# Jquery, each time click button a textfield appears

Tags: jquery-plugins

with jquery i want to make multiple text fields appear..
when click this text

```
<form>
<input  style="margin-top:20px;margin-right :50px; width:255px;height:23px;float:left;" type="text"  name="CrawlerField"id="CrawlerField"/>
<input style="margin-top: 15px; margin-right :50px; width:255px;height:23px;float:left;" type="text" name="CrawlerField1" id="CrawlerField1"/>
<input style="margin-top: 15px; margin-right :50px; width:255px;height:23px;float:left;" type="text" name="CrawlerField1" id="CrawlerField2"/>
<font id="jqueryAdd">Add button</font>
</form>
```

this is the text when clicked a new text field appears....

```
<font id="jqueryAdd">Add button</font>
```

script

at start all textfields are hidden

```
$("#CrawlerField1").hide();
$("#CrawlerField2").hide();
```

when click the word Add button defined with jqueryAdd
check if the previous textfield is hidden next textfield appears

```
$("#jqueryAdd").click(function ( event ) {
      if($("#CrawlerField").is(":visible"))
      $("#CrawlerField1").show();
        return false;
});
$("#jqueryAdd").click(function ( event ) {
      if($("#CrawlerField1").is(":visible"))
      $("#CrawlerField2").show();
  return false;
});
```

this code results in the appearance of all buttons at start !!

Answer (score 0):

add `class` to your all `<input>` tags like

```
 <input class ="in" style="margin-top:20px;margin-right :50px; width:255px;height:23px;float:left;" type="text"  name="CrawlerField"id="CrawlerField"/>
<input class ="in" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-right :50px; width:255px;height:23px;float:left;" type="text" name="CrawlerField1" id="CrawlerField1"/>
<input class ="in" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-right :50px; width:255px;height:23px;float:left;" type="text" name="CrawlerField1" id="CrawlerField2"/>
```

and in jquery add this line to hide all input initially.

```
$(".in").hide();
```